# Want to update java version specific to flyway

Tags: 14.04, java

I need to update java version inside flyway in Ubuntu. I have run 
apt-get update oracle-java8-installer, but it will update java version for default Java installed.
If I running update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/flyway/jre/bin/java 1 it is not updating the java version.

How to do it

Comment: Which version of Java do you want?

Comment: updated version of java,in my system it is 1.8.0.152,but i want to update with current version ...

Comment: how to rerun flyway to take upgrade version